# Depth-first traverse a tree with operation on each node except the root

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

I would like to traverse the nodes of a tree, and whenever visit a node, I would like to apply an operation on the node except when the node is the root.

If without the exception for the root, the pseudocode (in python style) is

```
def depth_first_search(root):

    operation(root)

    for child in root's children:
        depth_first_search(child)
```

With the exception for not operating on the root, how shall I modify the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can either
a: Call this function for each child of root, that way this procedure won't run on the root. Or,
b: Store a pointer to parent for each node. If a node has no parent, don't do the operation.
Hope this helps!